# C++20 feature not working Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (three-way comparison)

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3, c++20

I am trying to run the following code snippet on Sublime-Text on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    auto result = (10 <=> 5) > 0;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this results in

```
ModernC++.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ModernC++.cpp:3:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
    3 |  auto result = (10 <=> 5) > 0;
      |                      ^
[Finished in 271ms with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['g++ -std=c++2a ModernC++.cpp -o ModernC++ && timeout 7s ./ModernC++<input.txt>output.txt']]
[dir: /home/parth/.config/sublime-text/Packages/User]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

I have also tried running it directly from the terminal with the following command

```
g++ ModernC++.cpp -std=c++2a -o ModernC++
```

But this results in

```
ModernC++.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ModernC++.cpp:3:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
    3 |  auto result = (10 <=> 5) > 0;
```

I have tried the same code on my Windows 10 OS and it works fine there. I did a bit of research. I have found out that C++20 features are available from GCC 8 onwards. I checked my G++ version as well.

```
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

So I do not think version is the issue. Here is build-system file for sublime as well if someone can tell me a mistake in that as well.

```
{
    "cmd" : ["g++ -std=c++2a $file_name -o $file_base_name && timeout 7s ./$file_base_name<input.txt>output.txt"],
    "selector" : "source.cpp",
    "shell":true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

So here are my queries -

1. How do I fix the code not running in Sublime-Text?
2. How do I fix the code not running in Terminal?

I searched for fixes but only issue I found was version being too low and clearly that is not the case with my system. Also, C++17 standard code is working fine.

EDIT 1: changed g++ to g++-10, still the same error.

EDIT 2: Fixed, <=> was mistakenly changed to <= > for some reason.

Comment: *Some* C++20 features are available since GCC8. Three way comparison wasn't added until GCC10 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need atleast version 10 in GCC.
check the compiler support
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: So I wont' be able to use three way comparison in Ubuntu then? I think when I tried to update GCC it said it is latest version 9.3.0.

Comment: You can  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298443/when-gcc-11-will-appear-in-ubuntu-repositories